# What's the simplest way to retrieve the latest subversion tag from SVN?

Tags: svn, version-control

When we tag, we use the following format. `YYYYMMDD_SPRINTNAME`

We have multiple environments and each environment should only have that particular sprint (TV show name) installed. For example, our UAT environment is working off the `FRIENDS` code base. Our QA environment is working off the `LAWORDER` code base.

When we tag, they all go into the same repository (unlike our branches). So running an `svn ls <PATH_TO_REPO> | tail -n1` won't work. What I would like to have happen is run the same command for each sprint name and grabbing the latest tag for that particular sprint.

For example, `svn ls http://devbox/repos/projectname/tags` will show the following. The latest tag is at the bottom (tail -n1 will work but not always).

```
20121210_CHOPPED
20121219_FRIENDS
20121220_MASH
20121220_FRIENDS
20121220_LAWORDER
```

So there could be an instance where we wanted to grab the latest tag for the `FRIENDS` sprint?

Comment: What about just `svn ls <PATH_TO_REPO> | grep '_FRIENDS' | tail -n1`?

Comment: WTF was I thinking, this works. For whatever reason it wasn't working on my laptop but appears to work fine on my desktop. Go figure.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of blindly rely on the results of tail, contrary to @msell code, I'll suggest hand-made logic and small change in ls

`svn ls -v ROOT-OF-TAGS`

in this case first column of each tag will be revision of creation and after grep highest revision can be detected based on **number, not order**

Answer (score 2):

Subversion tags are just directories just like branches. There has been some controversy with this design because tags can be easily modified (just like branches and directories) without much notice. One of the first things I did was to create a pre-commit hook to allow people to create a tag, but prevent tags from being modified.

However, one of the great things about this design is that tags have the full power of Subversion attached to them. You can see who created the tag, when, and why. You can see where the tag is from, what revision, and who may have modified it.

This means that if all of your tags are directly under the tags directory, you can simply use `svn log` to look at the changes in the `/tags` directory:

```
$ svn log -v $REPO/tags
```

The very first entry will be the very last tag created. If you use Python or Perl, you can have a script that will run on both PCs and (U|li)nix systems that will return the last tag created.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using svn log would give you what you want, for example:

```
$ svn log http://some/repos/tags
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r4443 | joe | 2012-12-18 15:35:27 -0800 (Tue, 18 Dec 2012) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /tags/release-2.2.3.1-ga (from /branches/release-2.2:4442)

------------------------------------------------------------------------
r4345 | joe | 2012-11-21 17:40:11 -0800 (Wed, 21 Nov 2012) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /tags/release-1.7.4.1-ga (from /branches/release-1.7.4:3872)

Create tag for 1.1.4.1

...
```

So you could either use some shell tools to pick out your sprint name, or read in the XML formatted log output (svn log --xml) and pick it out of there.  Whichever method you're more adept at.